How to use Internal app sharing in development life cycle of the project, SIT, UAT, PREPROD, PROD etc
I want to understand the full usages of internal app sharing provided by google play store which is also recommended way of distributing app with testers. However I don't feel internal app sharing is useful for entire development life cycle of project. We may need parallel testing in SIT, UAT, PROD pointing to different environments. How would be able to leverage internal app sharing in that case, will there be a history where tester can download older builds as well?
Let me know if there is a way to maintain multiple builds at the time in internal app sharing?
I know we can promote builds from one stage to another stage (between open testing, close testing, beta testing). Will it allow same tester to test SIT and UAT simultaneously for example.
Please help me understanding if internal app testing recommended in my case or I should go with some other tools like Firebase distribution.
Let me know if I missing anything.
